# Problems with BASH variable multiplication inside if statment

Tags: bash, if-statement, math

I am having an issue getting BASH to update a variable in a piece of scripting that I am working on. Below is an excerpt from my script that I have having troubles with

```
read -p "Did you plan on running the server from a Ramdisk?(y/n)" RAMDISK
        if [[ "$RAMDISK" == [yY] ]]; then
                read -p "What is the full path to where you would like to create the ramdisk?(/var/RAMDISK)" RAMDIR
                read -p "How big did you want the ramdisk to be?(2048)" RAMSIZE
                if [[ "$RAMSIZE" -lt 1024 ]]; then
                        $NEWRAMSIZE = $((RAMSIZE*1024)) #FIXME
                        echo $NEWRAMSIZE
                fi
                RAMDISK="Enabled"
        fi

        if [[ "$RAMDISK" == [nN] ]]; then
                RAMDISK="Disabled"
        fi
        echo $NEWRAMSIZE
```

My problem is that no matter what I am trying, the RAMSIZE variable never gets multiplied by 1024. I am trying to make it so no matter what number you enter, it will always get changed to a size in mb instead of gb, assuming anything less than 1024 is a gb size.  Earlier in the script RAMSIZE defaults to 2048 and it never seems to be changed during the if statement. Please help?

Comment: No space when assigning values to a variable:  `NEWRAMSIZE=$(( RAMSIZE*1024 ))`

Comment: See if you can spot the difference between your `RAMDISK="Disabled"` and `$NEWRAMSIZE = $((RAMSIZE*1024))` lines.

Comment: Read [Before asking about problematic code](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three problems: you shouldn't have spaces around the `=` in an assignment, you shouldn't use `$` on the variable you're assigning to (`$variable` is how you *get* the value of a variable, not how you *set* it), and you're using `RAMSIZE` in some places and `NEWRAMSIZE` in others. The critical lines are:

```
if [[ "$RAMSIZE" -lt 1024 ]]; then
    RAMSIZE=$((RAMSIZE*1024)) # Note: no spaces, no extra $, same variable
    echo $NEWRAMSIZE
fi

...

echo "$RAMSIZE" # Same variable
```

BTW, you can use [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) to spot basic problems like this.

Comment: I didn't realize I hadn't switched variables back before posting this code, I was playing with assigning the new value of RAMSIZE to NEWRAMSIZE, but you hit it right on the head, thanks a ton! Also that is a pretty handy link to keep around, thanks again.